# Order entire groups of results by highest value in each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

For example, let's say that I have a table in PostgreSQL (higher than 9.0), filled with data:

```
row_id    percent    isrc
1         100        123iee43
2         100        1234wr32
3         98         123iee43
4         99         1234wr32
5         95         12313be3
6         99         12313be3
7         96         12313be3
```

I would like my result to contain ALL of the above rows grouped by column `isrc` and then entire groups ordered by `percent`, descending. So this is what the result should look like:

```
row_id    percent    isrc
1         100        123iee43
3         98         123iee43
2         100        1234wr32
4         99         1234wr32
6         99         12313be3
7         96         12313be3
5         95         12313be3
```

If I wanted ascending order, this is what I'd expect (I want to order only by the first row in one group, other rows in a single group do not matter):

```
row_id    percent    isrc
6         99         12313be3
7         96         12313be3
5         95         12313be3
1         100        123iee43
3         98         123iee43
2         100        1234wr32
4         99         1234wr32
```

I guess I must use *window functions* somehow but was unable to find the correct solution if one exists. Also, it would be really neat if the solution was as *elegant* as possible. :)

Comment: Why do you display `123iee43` before `1234wr32` in the third listing? It should be the other way round. Also: how do you want to sort `isrc`? Ascending, Descending or not at all? This is relevant to break ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Window function

```
SELECT row_id, percent, isrc
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY max(percent) OVER(PARTITION BY isrc) DESC, isrc, percent DESC;
```

The aggregate function `max()` can be used as window function. I don't use `ORDER BY` in the window clause because, [per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

> When an aggregate function is used as a window function, it aggregates
>   over the rows within the current row's window frame. An aggregate used
>   with `ORDER BY` and the default window frame definition produces a
>   "running sum" type of behavior, which may or may not be what's wanted.
>   To obtain aggregation over the whole partition, omit `ORDER BY` or use
>   `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`. Other frame
>   specifications can be used to obtain other effects.

Window function cannot be used in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause, because those are applied *before* the window function. But you *can* use one in the `ORDER BY` clause, which is applied last (even after `DISTINCT`, but before `LIMIT`).

Window functions can be expensive, but this one simplifies the query so much, it may even be faster than alternatives.
And it is certainly the most **elegant**.

#### Aggregate function

Plus `JOIN`. May or may not be faster.

```
SELECT row_id, percent, isrc
FROM   tbl
JOIN  (SELECT isrc, max(percent) AS max_pct FROM tbl GROUP BY 1) x USING (isrc)
ORDER  BY x.max_pct DESC, isrc, percent DESC;
```

#### `DISTINCT ON`

Very similar to using an aggregate function.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   tbl t
JOIN  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (isrc) isrc, percent
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY isrc, percent DESC
    ) s USING (isrc)
ORDER BY s.percent DESC, s.isrc, t.percent DESC
```

You *don't* need a window function here.

[**SQL Fiddle** demonstrating all of the above.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fca9a/5)

Comment: Really comprehensive answer! Thank you!

Comment: @RokDominko: You're welcome. :) Would you be so kind as to run these alternatives (including Clodoaldo's) with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) and report back on the performance (plus Postgres version and number of rows in your tables)?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/642db/2)

```
select t.*
from
    t
    inner join (
        select distinct on (isrc) isrc,
            row_number() over(order by percent desc) rn
        from t
        order by isrc, percent desc
    ) s on t.isrc = s.isrc
order by s.rn, t.percent desc
```